# Need help to come up with a Workflow system

Tags: php, workflow, desktop-application, business-process-management

I am planning to develop a web based work flow system which also provides drag-n-drop option of different entities for workflow creation and form builder. Primarily I am looking a solution in PHP but if could not then I can go for Java.

I got something about ezComponnts but I also need a Visualization, something like [this](http://www.dailymotion.com/video/xbuiry_free-workflow-with-flowmind-org-qui_tech) so I wonder what could be the best bet for me? ezComponnt looks good programatically, is there anyway I can integrate visual interface and a Form builder in it? Or I make visual builder as a Desktop program and then export the entire workflow in some TextFile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [ProcessMaker](http://processmaker.com), which provides most of your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

[WSO2 Business Process Server](http://wso2.com/products/business-process-server) provides a complete web-based graphical console to deploy, manage and view processes. It is Powered by the Apache Orchestration Director Engine (ODE) BPEL engine.

Latest snapshot distribution is available at http://wso2.org/bamboo/browse/WSO2CARBON-PRODUCTS-235/artifact/JOB1/BPS

[WSO2 Developer Studio](http://wso2.com/products/developer-studio) provides eclipse based development environment to develop deployable artifacts on BPS engine.